# PROC SQL left join on id and date not working

Tags: date, merge, proc-sql

I am trying to merge two tables with below code:

```sql
proc sql;
create table test as
select a.*, b.*
from aaa a
left join bbb b on a.id=b.id and a.date1<=b.date2;
quit;
```

But the output shows blanks in columns from table `b`.

However if I change it to `a.date1>=b.date2` it seems to work. Why would this be happening?

Checks I have done to be sure: 1) date formats are ok; 2) there are dates in table `aaa` which are less and more than table `b` dates.
Please help!

Comment: A left join can theoretically have blanks (null values) in its output. Do you have some data where the _id_ matches but you would expect records with _date2_ values on either side of the _date1_ value?

Comment: yes I have checked the spreadsheets manually there are dates on either side.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select a.*, b.*
from aaa a
left join bbb b on a.id=b.id and datepart(a.date1)<=datepart(b.date2);
quit;
```

ok so looks like when I add datepart to both dates it works perfectly fine. Hopefully this will come in handy to someone.